# Extending the DOM

Tags: javascript

I've recently read that extending the DOM on the whole is bad, because of reasons listed [here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/) and [here](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/). As I understand it, the main reasons against it are:

- It doesn't work very well/at all in IE
- It is possible to run into conflict, such as if a framework uses `Document.prototype.hide` and a browser then implements a `hide` function on document elements
- Browsers implement things in wildly different ways

However, I haven't seen anyone ask these questions.

1. If I wanted to extend the DOM, how would I do it safely? Besides the
   obvious use of a wrapper, how would I natively add a function, such
   as `hide` to the DOM as a whole, safely?
2. If it's not possible to implement it safely, what are the specific
       reasons? Can I implement checks, such as checking `typeof
       Document.prototype.hide == 'undefined'` before implementing my own
       function on the prototype?

In other words, explain to me how I can extend the DOM safely and what I could do to make sure that if a browser were to make the `hide` function, what I could do to not make my code have to be completely reworked.

Comment: Why do you want to *extend* the DOM? It is mostly a *standard* which should work on *many* recent browsers (not everyone is browsing the web with IE). Indeed, it is complex and clumsy, as most web standards are....

Comment: [Er...](http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/03/24/on-principle/)

Comment: I'm mainly just curious about it. I have heard the same argument against it, and that extending the DOM led to problems with `prototype.js` but nothing for, or what could be done to extend it safely. The only little bit I've seen is that Mootools does it a little differently but gets around some of prototype's problems.

Comment: I think jQuery extended the DOM. You should look at its code.